# TLC model checker doesn't terminate on an and/or list version of formula

Tags: tla+

This is probably a very stupid question, but I'll ask anyway.

I'm watching Leslie Lamport's videos about TLA+. In [video number four](http://lamport.azurewebsites.net/video/video4.html), called "Die Hard", he gives an exercise of implementing `BigToSmall` and `SmallToBig` formulas. Long story short: we need to correctly calculate how much water is in 3 and 5 gallon jugs after pouring from one to another.

This is his solution:

```
SmallToBig == IF big + small =< 5
               THEN /\ big'   = big + small
                    /\ small' = 0
               ELSE /\ big'   = 5
                    /\ small' = small - (5 - big)

BigToSmall == IF big + small =< 3
               THEN /\ big'   = 0 
                    /\ small' = big + small
               ELSE /\ big'   = small - (3 - big)
                    /\ small' = 3
```

I tried to go with this and/or list thingy:

```
SmallToBig == \/ /\ big + small =< 5
                 /\ big'   = big + small
                 /\ small' = 0
              \/ /\ big'   = 5
                 /\ small' = small - (5 - big)

BigToSmall == \/ /\ big + small =< 3
                 /\ big'   = 0 
                 /\ small' = big + small
              \/ /\ big'   = small - (3 - big)
                 /\ small' = 3
```

however it when I run it, the checking doesn't terminate, and I cannot figure out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I rewrite it as

```
\* Old
SmallToBig == 
   IF Condition
     THEN A
     ELSE B

\* New
SmallToBig == 
  \/ /\ Condition
     /\ A
  \/ B
```

In both versions, we can't have `A` without `Condition`. In the old version, we can't have `B` *with* `Condition`. In the new version, though, we can have `B` with `Condition`: it's a valid action.

Answer (score 1):

Have TLC check the [invariant `TypeOK`](https://github.com/tlaplus/Examples/blob/536628fc9ec15263f17e5849f0a9a8e2fa20241d/specifications/DieHard/DieHard.tla#L38-L39). The counterexample will show you what is going on.